# Adding text for each line in getoutput()

Tags: python, bash, for-loop

I have a problem with figuring out how to add text for each line of `getoutput` method in python.

The code look like this:

```
...
def mloop():
 for i in csv2hash(SLIST):
    ...
    if i.get('IP'):
        r = getoutput(CMD3 % (i['IP'])
        for line in iter(r):
           print i['IP']
...
```

The problem is that if I try this code, it will show me syntax error for a ":" in `iter(r):` and if i delete ":"(which i guess i should not do...) it will show syntax error for `print`. The CMD3 variable is a bash script for listing all files from folder on ssh server. And after all processing it all goes into csv (which code i did not include here)

I could just add IP in bash script, however I want to do this in python.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You should update your question with enough information and code for us to reproduce the problem. You'll get a better response from the community if you make it easier for us to help you. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on the `getoutput()` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will solve your problem. Try this.

```
  def mloop():
     for i in csv2hash(SLIST):
        ...
        if i.get('IP'):
            r = getoutput(CMD3 % (i['IP']))
            for line in iter(r):
               print (i['IP'])
```

Comment: yes it works, thanks :) and also, how jasonharper said... i somehow deleted one parenthesis ... Stupid mistakes :p